# Add more column titles to Google Pie Chart

Tags: google-visualization

my query is GROUP BY 2 columns and I need to show that second column in the chart legend. I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked. Can some please assist.

Thanks
Angel

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();        
data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
data.addColumn('number', 'Pounds');

    for(i=0;i<my_2d.length;i++)
    data.addRow([
        my_2d[i] [0],
        parseInt(my_2d[i] [2])
    ]);
```

Comment: not sure I understand the question, but if you're trying to reference the second element in `my_2d[i]` then it should be 1, not 2 --> `my_2d[i][1]`

Comment: I'm not looking to reference another data point. I'm looking to add another data point as a description. I want to add an additional column to the legend. 

Here's the data array:

````["Amazon","Meats","1100","1","32746"],
["Amazon","Misc. Dry Food","300","1","32746"]
````

I need to display the following in the legend.

Amazon and Meats
Amazon and Misc. Dry Food

Right now it only reads as follows, which is confusing
Amazon
Amazon


Thanks
Angel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Pie Chart only accepts one additional column, which is for a tooltip when hovering a slice, see the [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format).

however, if you're simply wanting to add more information to the legend entries,
you can simply append the values when adding to the data table, as follows...

```
my_2d[i][0] + ' - ' + my_2d[i][1]


var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();        
data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
data.addColumn('number', 'Pounds');

for(i=0;i<my_2d.length;i++)
data.addRow([
    my_2d[i][0] + ' - ' + my_2d[i][1],  // <-- here
    parseInt(my_2d[i] [2])
]);
```